# Design mode infinite loading when editing drawable in Android Studio (4.1.2)

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have opened the default `launch_background.xml` file in Android Studio of a flutter project. If I choose the "Design" mode or "Split" mode, the same thing happens : there's an infinite "Loading" displaying:
[image]

Note I've made no modification in the original file. Is it normal ? Is it a known bug ? I've found nothing searching on Google.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the same that the answer of another of my question : click "Open for Editing in Android Studio" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66357891/2099888