# Bitmap not recognized in flutter launch_background.xml

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I want to change the default splash screen of my flutter project. So I've first changed the color to `holo_orange_dark` in `launch_background.xml`. It works.

Now, I want to add a bitmap, as suggested in a comment in the default file. I've placed a file named `splash.png` in app/src/main/res/drawable and others with the same name in all mipmap... folders, as you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

I've an error `Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/splash'`. Have I to declare this drawable in another place of my project ? (Note : I've tried to reference `splash.png` - with file extension - with same result)

If I run my project, I have an compile error that has nothing to do with that (gradle version on inapp_webview. If a remove the bitmap item, the strange compile disappear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see this at the top right when you're editing the xml file. Click open for editing in android studio

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: OK. It works. No error in the new Android Studio Window. But I have to confess that I do not understand what is thre reason for doing that. 
Is there any documentation that addresses this point? (link...)

Comment: I believe when you're working on a flutter application, Android studio uses the flutter plugins and settings at that point which doesn't recognize native android elements. Opening the android section in another Android studio window opens the android folder with the native android settings, same way you'll edit iOS files using XCode.